# Google ads showing up on emulator, but not on phones that bought app on market?

Tags: android, admob

I have an app on the market, and I recently decided to add Google Ads to it.  I'll get straight to the point.  The sample ads on the emulator work perfect, but on my atrix, which I bought the app on, they don' show up.  Here are my .xml for the ad, and the manifest.  Also, I don't call to retrieve an ad in the .java because I have it set to automatically get ads in the .xml.  Also, on the admob website, i have auto refresh set to on, and extra google ads on.  no filters either.  Help??

---

```
<com.google.ads.AdView 
                    android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_below="@id/logo"
                     ads:adUnitId=""
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true">

</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

---

```
 <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: mine works without ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
 try removing that

Comment: Okay I will try this, although I'll wait a little more time before updating.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you adding ads to a paid app? The rage from the users will scorch your house!

Comment: I was goiinngg to, but do you strongly advise not to?

Answer (score 1):

Did you include the `alphanumeric` ad code in your application?

If you are still having problems with implementing ads, you can try this [link](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/admob-manager/).

Comment: Don't know what that is, so probably not ha.

Comment: The code would look something like this `a14db01ee16f245`. Your can get it after adding a site in your admob profile. This would need to go into your code somewhere. The link in the answer provides a step by step guide to how to add ads to your application. Very useful.

Comment: yes I did this.  And It works, I just accidentally released it in test mode, so I changed that setting on the admob website, and waited a day, and it works now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is your Atrix rooted? Many developers add ad-blockers to their ROMs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is wrong, but I use this same setup for all my apps and it works like a charm in both real and emulated devices. Your manifest setup is fine.

**Main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/adMob"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >
</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity:**

```
void adMob() {
    // Create the adView
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "XxxxxxxXxxxx"); //admob ID

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    //adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR); // Emulator
    //adRequest.addTestDevice("6.......7");  // my phone

    // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adMob);
    layout.removeAllViews();

    // Add the adView to it
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```